# jquery dialog external page events are not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I open an html page using jquery dialog.

```
var url = "Popup.htm";
$('<div id=DialogDiv>').dialog({
            dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load(url);
            },
            close: function (e) {
                $(this).empty();
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            },
            height: 350,                              
            width: 540,
            title: 'Lookup'
        });
```

The above code opens Popup.htm in a modal dialog.The Popup.htm has got a button but the click event is not firing.Please help.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<title>PopUpView</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {


        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "http://localhost:3340/Service1.svc/FetchAllCompany",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('ok');
                    var div = $("#test").empty();
                    $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {
                        div.append(
                $("<tr>").append($("<td>").html(item.COMP_CODE))
                .append($("<td>").html(item.COMP_NAME))
                .append($("<td>").html(item.COMP_FRZ_FLAG)));
                    });
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {                        
                    debugger;
                }
            });

        });
    })

</script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="MainContentDiv">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input />
    <button id="btnSearch">...</button>
    <div>
        <table id="test">    
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The click event for btnSearch is not firing

Comment: I guess you are trying to add your HTML content by jQuery or JavaScript that's why JavaScript not able to find "btnSearch" ID in DOM to bind click event in it. Use on instead click

Comment: even on click  isn't firing

Comment: Is it online? Can you share URL so that i can try to debug?

Comment: Is there any js error output in the console?

Comment: no errors. it just dont fire.

Comment: Are you triggering ajax request with the same port?.. If not so, kindly check the same-origin policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Comment: the html page is in the same domain.infact in the same project.

Comment: If your are using chrome please right click in the console and activate **Log XMLHttpRequest**. You might have `XMLHttpRequest cannot load "blabla/Popup.htm". Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` **Also the last }) in Popup.htm should be })(); it could be the error**.

Comment: the page is loaded with all the elements.also if i invoke the page seperately it works fine.

Comment: Did you fix `$(function () {})` by adding the semicolon? Like `$(function () {});`

Comment: hi phemios,it didnt solve the issue.